# Visual studio - how to set output .lib path?

Tags: c++, visual-studio

This is my setup with 2020 mode:

[image]

[image]

---

on 2022 mode is similar!

[image]

[image]

However when I build with target 2020,

```
the output of .lib is
$(ProjectDir)x64\Release2020
and, for target 2022 it is:
$(SolutionDir)x64\Release2022
```

I don't change anything in propertypage,
Where can I check other settings?

[image]

I need to set the output file in $(solutiondir)Release..

Comment: Just edit the project files directly.  You can change the macros and be more flexible than you can with the IDE editor.  You can also find things by searching for text!  IIRC, the file extension is `cxxproj` or something like that.

Comment: Hi @JDługosz I couldn't find the cause. An option has turned it off. finally, I
delete and copy setting 2022 solved the problem now. Thank you for the suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

Ok. I saw it. just change IntDir to OutDir. my's problem is solved.

[image]

Comment: I am glad you have got your solution and thanks for your sharing, I would appreciate it if you mark them as answer and this will be beneficial to other community.